# Should the content editing modal be part of of the ContentCard component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a React app. Basically there are some contents and listing sections.

My questions is for editing content, should the content editing modal be part of of the ContentCard component or should i place the `ContentEditModal` in `MainLayout` ?

User will use `ContentEditModal`, only when click the edit button. So repeating the same component is an anti-pattern? Or what is the best way to do this?

Let me summarize;

**Approach 1 :**

```
MainLayout

--ContentList

----Content (ContentCardComponent With Edit Modal Inside)
----Content (ContentCardComponent With Edit Modal Inside)
----Content (ContentCardComponent With Edit Modal Inside)
----Content (ContentCardComponent With Edit Modal Inside)
...
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
MainLayout

--ContentEditModal

--ContentList
----Content (ContentCardComponent Without Edit Modal)
----Content (ContentCardComponent Without Edit Modal)
----Content (ContentCardComponent Without Edit Modal)
----Content (ContentCardComponent Without Edit Modal)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Second approach makes it easier for another developer to find the modal if he has to work on it. Also, having the modal in a different component makes the components lighter, easier to test and more predictable. Also having the modal in it's own component makes it reusable so you might avoid repeating code in the future.
Basically the "separation of concerns" concept is always your friend.